# rake environment elastic search:import:all FORCE=y keeps failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm running search kick and elastic search and i keep trying to recreate my index because my rails app is crashing but this keeps failing too. I am very new to this so feeling quite lost.

I run `rake environment elasticsearch:import:all FORCE=y`

But the error is

```
Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with 
[IMPORT] Loading models from: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/models
2016-03-11 16:32:07 +0000: [Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 {:host=>"localhost", :port=>9200, :protocol=>"http"}
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: users does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.8/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:118:in `import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.8/lib/elasticsearch/model.rb:115:in `import'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:109:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/elasticsearch-rails-0.1.8/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:93:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/elasticsearch-rails-0.1.8/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:87:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/elasticsearch-rails-0.1.8/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => elasticsearch:import:all
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5: How to import data in Elastic Search and perform conditional search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525523/rails-5-how-to-import-data-in-elastic-search-and-perform-conditional-search)

Answer (score 3):

We were having the same issue this morning.

The [elastic-search-model](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) documentation tells you to set up your models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  #The rest of your mode...
end

User.import
```

But before importing your existing data, you need to remove `User.import` then run `rake environment elasticsearch:import:all FORCE=y` and everything will go smoothly.

Remember to add `User.import` after running the rake task so your new users will be imported properly.

Happy Coding!

Comment: i got this Don't know how to build task 'elasticsearch:import:all' (see --tasks) :(

Comment: What do you mean to build the task? The rake task will be available when you install the gem.

Comment: The documentation is still not updated - taking out User.import is important here.

Comment: @cahyowhy From https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails#rake-tasks, ...in the lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake file:
`require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'`

Answer (score 0):

try `YourModelName.import(force: true)` in rails console.