# Rails 5: How to import data in Elastic Search and perform conditional search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model named **Product**. I provided a full text search to search products and producing a type-ahead on the client side using AngularJS. The search query was a normal like query as :

```
select * from products where name like = %abc% and company_id = 123;
```

However as my records in the table grew, the search time using the above method increased, so I decided to implement elastic search. I'm using two gems gem `'elasticsearch-model'and gem 'elasticsearch-rails'`.
How can I index the **Product Model**. I tried using this `Product._elasticsearch_.create_index!` command in the **rails console** it gave the following error :

```
2.4.0 :006 > Product._elasticsearch_.create_index!
ArgumentError: products does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it.
```

Below are my implementations :

**The Product Model**

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :gst
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invoice_details
  self.per_page = 100

  Product.import
end
```

Comment: Paras, is the `Product.import` line in the `product.rb` file? And you should create two questions, becuse you are asking two things in this question.

Comment: Yes it is. Sure I would do that. Thanks.

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano where should the Product.import line be?

Comment: @ManoharsinhRana it should be in a script that u should run for migrating from you DB to ElasticSearch

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano If I run Product.import in rails console in the terminal will this work?

Comment: @ManoharsinhRana yep, it's something that's added when u include  the `Elasticsearch::Model` module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you do not have a `products` index created, [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb#L115-L120) you can see the code of the gem where the error is raised.

Take a close look at this [line](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb#L117), the `!self.index_exists? index: target_index`, it checks if the index exists, if not the error is Raised.

So you have two options here, to force the import like this: `Product.import(force: true)`, be aware that this destroys the index if it exists and creates it again.

The other option is to first create the index an then do the import:

```
Product.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
Product.import
```

I recommend to you to read how to map your model to the index in elasticsearch. [Link1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#index-configuration), [Link2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html). Because in order to query, you need to understand how your index is created.

Comment: You can also do it all in oneline with: `Product.import force: true`